# WaitForSingleObject() not returning WAIT_ABANDONED

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have an MFC application. In InitInstance() I created a named mutex and acquiring it immediately by calling WaitForSingleObject(). In the ExitInstance() the mutex is released.

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    m_hMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, "MyAppMutex" );
    DWORD dwRes = WaitForSingleObject( m_hMutex, INFINITE );
    switch( dwRes )
    {
    case WAIT_ABANDONED:
        break;
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        break;
    }
}

BOOL CMyApp::ExitInstance()
{
    ::ReleaseMutex( m_hMutex );
    ::CloseHandle( m_hMutex );
}
```

What I understand from Mutex documentation is that If a process exits with out releasing the acquired mutex, when another process tries to acquire it WaitForXXXObject() will return WAIT_ABANDONED.

For testing this I ran my application and killed it using task manager so that ReleaseMutex wont be called. But when I ran the application again WaitForSingleObject() in InitInstance() returns WAIT_OBJECT_0. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: Pretty unclear what "relaunched the application" has to do with this.  You can only get WAIT_ABANDONED when you start *another* process that called OpenMutex().

Comment: By relaunch I mean the application is started again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [MSDN page on `CreateMutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx) :

> The system closes the handle automatically when the process terminates. The mutex object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.

It is true that the mutex will be in an abandoned state when you terminate the process, but the 2nd sentence tells us that the mutex won't even exist anymore if you terminated the only process that opened it.

When you re-launch your application, you recreate a new mutex because no other process had a handle to it.